# PK, FK Constraints design

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following tables structure.

```
TABLE1
SALARY_DETAILS(N_EMP_ID, D_MONTH ...)
N_EMP_ID NUMBER
D_MONTH DATE

PRIMARY KEY being composite: N_EMP_ID,D_MONTH

TABLE 2
INCOME_TAX(N_EMP_ID,D_YEAR,N_TAX...)
```

I want N_EMP_ID in TABLE2 to be a FOREIGN KEY on TABLE1(N_EMP_ID).
Now this gives the following error:-

[image: error]

I understand the table being referred to has PK on both N_EMP_ID and D_MONTH.
Obviously I shouldn't then do the below.

```
ALTER TABLE income_tax ADD FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES salary_details(V_EMP_ID,D_MONTH);
```

- Question 1: What is the right way/design to fix this?
- Question 2: Can I have both PK and FK constraints on the same column: INCOME_TAX(V_EMP_ID)?

Thanks for your inputs.

Here is the Create table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE "ANKUR"."SALARY_DETAILS" 
   (    
    "V_EMP_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "D_MONTH" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "V_EMP_ID" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "N_NET_PAY" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_TOT_EARNINGS" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_TOT_DED" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_BAS_SAL" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_FDA" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_HRA" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_MED_ALLW" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_TRANS_ALLW" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_LTA" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_BON_EXGRA_ADV" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_ANN_BON_EXGRA" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_PERF_BON" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_LWF" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_INCM_TAX" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_INFY_WELTRUST" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_MLPL" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_LIB_DEDUC" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "N_PF" NUMBER(10,2), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_PERSON" PRIMARY KEY ("V_EMP_ID", "D_MONTH")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

Comment: Please show the *complete* `create table` statement for the `salary_details` table.

Comment: Added a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: The PK in `salary_details` consists of **two** columns. You can't reference a PK with two columns through a FK with only **one** column. Why is the `D_MONTH` column part of the PK in the first place? This mean you are allowing the **same** `V_EMP_ID` values for different `D_MONTH` values? That doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `D_MONTH` would contain the first day of the month like 1-Apr-2014, 1-May-2014 etc. So I can have month-wise salary details for multiple employees, therefore requiring both `V_EMP_ID` and `D_MONTH` as PK columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EMPLOYEES should be a separate table that both SALARY_DETAILS and INCOME_TAX refer to. This way, you can eliminate redundancy and also fix your FK problems.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @ammoQ. In that case, for `SALARY_DETAILS` PK would remain as `V_EMP_ID` and `D_MONTH` and FK would be on `V_EMP_ID` of `EMPLOYEES. Right?

Comment: Thanks @ammoQ. Also, while changing the `INCOME_TAX` table by `ALTER TABLE INCOME_TAX RENAME COLUMN PERSON_ID TO V_EMP_ID;` so that I can apply its FK on `EMPLOYESS`, I ran into `ORA-02250` (missing or invalid constraint name) although I have no constraints on `PERSON_ID`. Any thoughts on that.

Comment: Technically there is no need to rename the column. You might want to do that for consistency, though. The reason for the ORA-02550 is probably the exsiting primary key constraint that includes that table. Drop it an recreate it after the rename.

Comment: Strange. There is no primary key constraint on this table `CREATE TABLE "ANKUR"."INCOME_TAX" 
   ( "PERSON_ID" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
 "D_YEAR" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "N_INCOME_TAX" NUMBER(10,2)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;`